# Tinkercad Circuit: How to Make the Built-in LED and LED light up through a push button

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

I am new to Arduino and I have a problem making the built-in LED of the arduino board as well as the external LED connected to a bread board light up through a click of a push button. When I run it, it doesn't do anything. It only prints 0 on the terminal continuously.

This is what my arduino looks like
[image]

And this is the code that I am working on:

```
 // C++ code
 int pushButton = 2;


 void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pushButton, INPUT);
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
 }

 void loop() {
  int buttonState = digitalRead(pushButton);
  if (buttonState == HIGH) {
  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
 } else {
 digitalWrite(13, LOW);
 }
 Serial.println(buttonState);
 delay(1000); // Delay the blink for a second
 }
```

Also, I have a question, what does the digital pin 2 signifies?

We just started learning this, and I'm exploring the process of making it. I'm lost. I do not know where the problem lies, if its on the structure of the board and the other components or in the code itself. Maybe you can help me with it. That would be a huge help.

Comment: I think your button is lacking anything to pull its value up, it is only connected to ground and the input pin

Comment: Can you give me an idea as to what I'm lacking? I'm going around the same circle with this problem every time I try to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Arduino UNO built-in LED is on pin 13 so you can refer to it using the LED_BUILTIN constant.

As for the push button, adding an internal PULLUP will work better (you can read about it in many posts).

Also note the usage of bool instead of int for buttonState, it is more appropriate to my opinion.

```
int pushButton = 2;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(pushButton, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  bool buttonState = digitalRead(pushButton);
  if (buttonState == LOW) {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  }
  Serial.println(buttonState);
  delay(1000); // Delay the blink for a second
}
```

Comment: Thank you big time! I was having a hard time until now and you cleared some of my questions. Will do explore more on the topic.